# Getting the value of toggle switch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to alert the value of the switch when it is changed, however some long code strand comes out in the alert box

HTML

```
<div align="right">
        <select name="switch" id="alleventsswitch" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
            <option value="off">No Past</option>
            <option value="on">Past</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#alleventsswitch').change( function() {

    alert($('select').slider().val);

});
```

apparently .val does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
$('#alleventsswitch').change(function () {
    console.log(this.value); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EgJE3/)**

Inside the handler `this` represent the select lement itself, you can access its value as `this.value`. By doing `$('select').slider()` you are unwantedly invoking the constructor plugin for slider which is not needed.. Also use console.log instead of alert especially incase of testing the slider which is susceptible to mouse movements. Also by doing `$('select').val()` you might end up getting the value of another select that may be present in DOM before this element, you want to target the current element in action use `this` inside the handler.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('#alleventsswitch').change( function() {
    alert($('select').val());
});
```

Working jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/6J6Fs/

If you want to specifically select the `select` element with `data-role="slider"`, you can use this:

```
$('#alleventsswitch').change( function() {
    alert($('select[data-role="slider"]').val());
});
```

Working jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/6J6Fs/1/

Hope this helps.